# How to define Spring bean with unique id (not within the file)?

Tags: java, spring, ioc-container

I've a lot of Spring xml files and I wish that each bean must have unique id (or name doesn't matter for me) for whole Spring scope. Cal I tell Spring to throw and exception in case of non uniqueness of beans id/names?

Comment: It will throw an error at runtime when it finds two beans with similar name(at runtime).

Comment: No. It's so called "Spring Beans Overwriting Strategy" http://www.dzone.com/links/r/spring_beans_overwriting_strategy.html Uniqueness only within the file (not whole Spring scope)!

Answer (score 1):

You can probably implement your own subclass of beanfactory which will check that a bean does not exist during registration and potentially look also in the parent context(s). 
A good method might be the registerBean?